# Flutter: How to pass data from one page to another and save it

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to the whole app development process so please help me out. I am working on a learning app, i have created two pages (the courses page and the my courses page)

1. the first page shows all the list of courses available. It displays the course description gotten from the api (such as the course code and title) in cards with a button that enables u to add or enroll in the course when tapped.
2. The second one is an empty page that is supposed to show the list of courses the user has enrolled in or added from the course page.

So wat i need help achieving is when a course button is tapped in the courses page (first page)..i want it to add the individual course in the second page (my courses page)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your post doesn't follow the guidelines. Please take a look at them and improve your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite some missing info in your question, but if I understood it correctly, you want to pass from screen A to screen B some kind of data, and based on that you want show different on the screen.

For passing data from one screen to the other you can use the `arguments` parameter when you call `Navigator.pushNamed()`. I would recommend define a class on your 2nd screen which defines which data you expect. It makes stuff easier in the future.

**Screen 2**

```
// Define the data you expect as arguments
class Screen2Arguments {
  final int courseId;

  Screen2Arguments({
    @required this.courseId,
  });
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  // Do not forget to register your route in main.dart 
  static const route = "/screen2";
  @override
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  Screen2Arguments args;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (args != ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments) {
      // Save the data passed to the screen in a variable.
      args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use your data, and render different screens / content
    switch (args.courseId) {
      case 1:
        // build / fetch your course with id 1
        break;
      case 2:
        // build / fetch your course with id 2
        break;
    }
    return ...
  }
}
```

**Screen 1:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen1State createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(

            child: Text("pass data to Screen2"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, Screen2.route,
          // Pass data  like this in pushNamed()
                arguments: Screen2Arguments(courseId: 1)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can read more in the official documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: Thanks alot dis really helped but i'm afraid my problem is not fully solved yet. D data doesn't store or get saved permanently in d second screen. D moment i press d back button nd tap on anoda course the previous course no longer appears in d second screen only d new one or wen i go through d bottom navigation bar d second screen is still empty. I want the courses to be saved in d second screen until d user decides to delete dem.  Ive tried inserting the route data to a list nd den geting the list view builder to build 4rm the list but it's still thesame. when i leave the page the data clears

Comment: If you want to persist data in your application you have to save the data on the device and not just keep it in the memory. There are some soltuions like Sqflite or SharedPreferences. Here is the official doc: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence